# List of Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I'm searching a way to store a collection of `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` used to order elements, and then to execute the stored list against a `IQueryable<T>` object (the underlying provider is Entity Framework).

For example, I would like to do something like this (**this is pseudo code**):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OrderClause<User> orderBys = new OrderClause<User>();
        orderBys.AddOrderBy(u => u.Firstname);
        orderBys.AddOrderBy(u => u.Lastname);
        orderBys.AddOrderBy(u => u.Age);

        Repository<User> userRepository = new Repository<User>();
        IEnumerable<User> result = userRepository.Query(orderBys.OrderByClauses);
    }
}
```

An order by clause (property on which to order):

```
public class OrderClause<T>
{
    public void AddOrderBy<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> orderBySelector)
    {
        _list.Add(orderBySelector);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, ???>>> OrderByClauses
    {
        get { return _list; }
    }
}
```

A repository with my query method:

```
public class Repository<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Query(IEnumerable<OrderClause<T>> clauses)
    {
        foreach (OrderClause<T, ???> clause in clauses)
        {
            _query = _query.OrderBy(clause);
        }

        return _query.ToList();
    }
}
```

My first idea was to convert the `Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>` into a string (the property name on which to sort). So basically, instead of storing a typed list (which is not possible because the TProperty is not constant), I store a list of string with the properties to sort on.

But this doesn't work because then I cannot reconstruct the `Expression` back (I need it because IQueryable.OrderBy takes a `Expression<Func<T, TKey>>` as parameter).

I also tried to dynamically create the Expression (with the help of Expression.Convert), to have a `Expression<Func<T, object>>` but then I got an exception from entity framework that said that it was not able to handle the Expression.Convert statement.

If possible, I do not want to use an external library like the [Dynamic Linq Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).

Comment: BTW, your code wouldn't work, you need to call `OrderBy()` once and use `ThenBy()` for subsequent calls.

Comment: As I stated in my question, this was just pseudo code... In fact, I had already a solution to my problem, but with the use of the Dynamic Linq Library which I wanted to avoid. So the ordering problem you mention was already solved :), but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where a `dynamic` / reflection solution may be appropriate.

I think you want something like this? (I've read between the lines and made some changes to your structure where I thought necessary).

```
public class OrderClauseList<T>
{
    private readonly List<LambdaExpression> _list = new List<LambdaExpression>();

    public void AddOrderBy<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> orderBySelector)
    {
        _list.Add(orderBySelector);
    }

    public IEnumerable<LambdaExpression> OrderByClauses
    {
        get { return _list; }
    }
}

public class Repository<T>
{
    private IQueryable<T> _source = ... // Don't know how this works

    public IEnumerable<T> Query(OrderClause<T> clauseList)
    {
        // Needs validation, e.g. null-reference or empty clause-list. 

        var clauses = clauseList.OrderByClauses;

        IOrderedQueryable<T> result = Queryable.OrderBy(_source, 
                                                        (dynamic)clauses.First());

        foreach (var clause in clauses.Skip(1))
        {
            result = Queryable.ThenBy(result, (dynamic)clause);
        }

        return result.ToList();
    }
}
```

The key trick is getting C# `dynamic` to do the horrible overload resolution and type-inference for us. What's more, I believe the above, despite the use of `dynamic`, is actually type-safe!

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to “store” all the sort clauses in something like `Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>` (that is, a function that calls the sorting methods):

```
public class OrderClause<T>
{
    private Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> m_orderingFunction;

    public void AddOrderBy<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> orderBySelector)
    {
        if (m_orderingFunction == null)
        {
            m_orderingFunction = q => q.OrderBy(orderBySelector);
        }
        else
        {
            // required so that m_orderingFunction doesn't reference itself
            var orderingFunction = m_orderingFunction;
            m_orderingFunction = q => orderingFunction(q).ThenBy(orderBySelector);
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Order(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        if (m_orderingFunction == null)
            return source;

        return m_orderingFunction(source);
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to deal with reflection or `dynamic`, all this code is type safe and relatively easy to understand.

Comment: Yes that's true, it's quite easy, but the problem with this solution is that you need a direct access to IQueryable. My list of OrderBy is intended to be used by the GUI (basically to abstract the query), so I don't want to have a Queryable object here... I would prefer to manage it in the Business Logic !

Comment: @Bidou I really don't understand what you're trying to say. If you want to keep `Repository` like in your pseudo code, just change its code to take the whole `OrderClause` and then do `return orderBys.Order(_query).ToList();`.

Comment: +1: This is a really nice solution and as you say, neatly dodges dynamic / reflection.

Comment: A nice solution indeed! It's probably harder to debug though, compared to the `dynamic` solution. I mean, there's no easy way to inspect the individual components (sort expressions) of an `OrderClause`, you have to apply it to an `IQueryable` to see what's inside.

Comment: @svick It's a bit difficult to explain everything in just a few words... But in fact, OrderClause<T> is more a QueryOption<T> where I have OrderBy as well as other things like Where predicate, paging, ...

The goal of this is to offer to the GUI the possibility to create a query without knowing how it works in the Business Logic (QueryOption<T> works with a DTO, for example QueryOption<UserDTO> but my Repository<T> with an entity object, for example QueytionOption<User>. That means that I'm doing a mapping somewhere in between...)

Comment: Thus, I think that it's not a good idea for this QueryOption<T> to have a reference on IQueryable<T>, isn't it?

Comment: @Bidou I don't see why would a dependence on `IQueryable<T>` be bad. What else is someone else going to use? But I have no idea how are you doing the mapping., which might change things.

Comment: For example because having a direct access to IQueryable<T> in the GUI gives the possibility to navigate through the whole EF graph with navigation properties (in my case, the IQueryable<T>'s provider is Entity Framework) which will bypass all my security logic! This is a reason why I choose a DTO pattern and why I don't want to have IQueryable in this QueryOption<T>. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Bidou I don't know what “security logic” are you talking about, but I think it doesn't make much sense trying to protect against malicious code in the GUI layer, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

You can store your lambda expressions in a collection as instances of the `LambdaExpression` type.

Or even better, store sort definitions, each of which, in addition to an expression, aslo stores a sorting direction.

Suppose you have the following extension method

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> source,
    SortDefinition sortDefinition) where T : class
{
    MethodInfo method;
    Type sortKeyType = sortDefinition.Expression.ReturnType;
    if (sortDefinition.Direction == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        method = MethodHelper.OrderBy.MakeGenericMethod(
            typeof(T),
            sortKeyType);
    }
    else
    {
        method = MethodHelper.OrderByDescending.MakeGenericMethod(
            typeof(T),
            sortKeyType);
    }

    var result = (IQueryable<T>)method.Invoke(
        null,
        new object[] { source, sortDefinition.Expression });
    return result;
}
```

and a similar method for `ThenBy`. Then you can do something like

```
myQueryable = myQueryable.OrderBy(sortDefinitions.First());

myQueryable = sortDefinitions.Skip(1).Aggregate(
   myQueryable,
   (current, sortDefinition) => current.ThenBy(sortDefinition));
```

Here are the definitions of `SortDefinition` and `MethodHelper`

```
public class SortDefinition
{
    public SortDirection Direction
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public LambdaExpression Expression
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

internal static class MethodHelper
{
    static MethodHelper()
    {
        OrderBy = GetOrderByMethod();
        ThenBy = GetThenByMethod();
        OrderByDescending = GetOrderByDescendingMethod();
        ThenByDescending = GetThenByDescendingMethod();
    }

    public static MethodInfo OrderBy
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static MethodInfo ThenBy
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static MethodInfo OrderByDescending
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public static MethodInfo ThenByDescending
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetOrderByMethod()
    {
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<object>, IOrderedQueryable<object>>> expr =
            q => q.OrderBy((Expression<Func<object, object>>)null);

        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetThenByMethod()
    {
        Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<object>, IOrderedQueryable<object>>> expr =
            q => q.ThenBy((Expression<Func<object, object>>)null);

        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetOrderByDescendingMethod()
    {
        Expression<Func<IQueryable<object>, IOrderedQueryable<object>>> expr =
            q => q.OrderByDescending((Expression<Func<object, object>>)null);

        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetThenByDescendingMethod()
    {
        Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<object>, IOrderedQueryable<object>>> expr =
            q => q.ThenByDescending((Expression<Func<object, object>>)null);

        return ((MethodCallExpression)expr.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great, thanks! However, the aggregation will probably not work (I didn't test it) since you need to call ThenBy/ThenByDescending if you want to do multiple sort...

Comment: Something else: to do the query, using the dynamic keywork as proposed by Ani is easier. Basically, it replaces your MethodHelper class. But thanks anyway for your helpful answer!

Comment: @Bidou: I tested it and found that aggregation with `OrderBy` doesn't work. Will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

in E.F. Core you could use the following helper class

```
public static class OrderBuilder
{
    public static IQueryable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, params Tuple<Expression<Func<TSource, object>>, bool>[] keySelectors)
    {
        if (keySelectors == null || keySelectors.Length == 0) return queryable;

        return keySelectors.Aggregate(queryable, (current, keySelector) => keySelector.Item2 ? current.OrderDescending(keySelector.Item1) : current.Order(keySelector.Item1));
    }

    private static bool IsOrdered<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable)
    {
        if (queryable == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(queryable));

        return queryable.Expression.Type == typeof(IOrderedQueryable<TSource>);
    }

    private static IQueryable<TSource> Order<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        if (!queryable.IsOrdered()) return queryable.OrderBy(keySelector);

        var orderedQuery = queryable as IOrderedQueryable<TSource>;

        return (orderedQuery ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).ThenBy(keySelector);
    }

    private static IQueryable<TSource> OrderDescending<TSource, TKey>(this IQueryable<TSource> queryable, Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> keySelector)
    {
        if (!queryable.IsOrdered()) return queryable.OrderByDescending(keySelector);

        var orderedQuery = queryable as IOrderedQueryable<TSource>;
        return (orderedQuery ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()).ThenByDescending(keySelector);
    }
}
```

and then use it as.. this example below with a class named Player with the following members..(code reduced for brevity)

```
 public class Player
 {
    ...

    public string FirstName { get; set; 
    public int GenderTypeId { get; set; } 
    public int PlayingExperience { get; set; }
```

You could combine the orderings as you like, sorting by gender, playing experience descending (notice the **true** value of the tuple), and first name..

```
    var combinedOrder = new[]
    {
        new Tuple<Expression<Func<Player, object>>, bool>(p => p.GenderTypeId, false),
        new Tuple<Expression<Func<Player, object>>, bool>(p => p.PlayingExperience, true),
        new Tuple<Expression<Func<Player, object>>, bool>(p => p.FirstName, false),
    };
```

and just do the order as follows

```
        var data = context.Set<Player>()
            .OrderBy(combinedOrder)
            .ToArray();
```